# Java - LibGDX - What is the difference between isKeyPressed and isKeyJustPressed?

Tags: java, libgdx

What is the difference between isKeyPressed and isKeyJustPressed?!

I searched the docs. for the difference and just found:

isKeyPressed: Returns whether the key is pressed.

isKeyJustPressed: Returns whether the key has just been pressed.

Anybody knows something that explains better?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**isKeyPressed** detects whether the key is pressed, keyDown and/or still pressed.

**isKeyJustPressed** detects the keyDown event (the last frame), triggering the event only once. Holding down the key does not trigger the event twice, you need to execute keyUp and then trigger it again.

Comment: These descriptions should be added to the methods javadoc, I think.

Comment: Or renamed to `isKeyDown` and `isKeyPressed` respectively.

Comment: I improved the answer a little bit more precise