# In the LibGDX InputProcessor, Does every KeyDown() have a corresponding KeyUp()?

Tags: java, libgdx, boolean, keydown, keyup

I want set a Boolean to be true when a button is pressed that is essential to make false when the same button is released.

```
 public boolean keyDown (int keycode) {

     switch (keycode) {
         case Keys.RIGHT:
         player.movingRight = True;
         //or
         //player.xVel = 1;
         break;

 public boolean keyUp (int keycode) {

     switch (keycode) {
         case Keys.RIGHT:
         player.movingRight = False;
         //or
         //player.xVel = 0;
         break;
```

Is this a safe method of achieving the results one would desire, or will there ever be a case that the Boolean is left at True?

Comment: The following sceneario can happen:
1.-user press and holds key.
2.-user minimizes/switches to another window/app.
3.-user releases key.
Then the keyup wasnt called for that key.

Comment: However in this situation we are guaranteed that the pause() code is run, and also if the user Exits the program we know dispose is called, so those issues will not create too much of a problem, but thank you very much.

Comment: @Lestat Actually I did a little bit of Experimentation, turns out keyUp() is automatically called before pause. So that is not an issue at all.

Comment: Thats good I didnt know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this method is safe.

What are the available cases to think about?!

Whenever we keyDown we set it to true and whenever we KeyUp we set it to false.

**BUT**

In my opinion using isKeyPressed or isKeyJustPressed is the best way to achieve what you want.

Check out this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40979622/java-libgdx-what-is-the-difference-between-iskeypressed-and-iskeyjustpressed) about the difference.